# wlan0 interface informations available in linux

Tags: 14.04, interface

I want all the information regarding wlan0 interface, like Mac Address, Received packet, Received bytes, Transmitted Packet, Transmitted bytes, Speed of transmission, etc..

Where can I find these details from Linux file system.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run:
`ifconfig wlan0` for information like ip, mac, packets and bytes transmitted
`iwconfig wlan0` for transmission speed, link quality, signal level, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  apart from this can u tell me any files like eth0 is available in /proc/net/dev

Comment: No need to thanks just accept the answer if you are satisfy. What are you going to achieve with `/proc/net` ?

Comment: Its just for knowing. Like an old saying "Everything in Linux is considered as file". So there has to be a file right?

Comment: There are in eg. such location as `/sys/class/net`, `/proc/net`, `/proc/sys/net`. Configuration files in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` or `/etc/network/interfaces`